# How to highlight icons like the iOS toolbar

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, core-graphics, uitabbar

I would like to create some custom toolbars using some of the images I also use for the iOS Tab Bar.  How do I highlight icons like Apple does on the Tab Bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note that I haven't personally done this, but it is what I would do had I the need and time.**

The `UIToolBar` seems to achieve the effect using 3 layers:

1. bottom most layer is the rounded rectangle with black-gray shading
2. second layer is the blue hilight gradient
3. the topmost layer is the user supplied image, of which only the alpha channel is used.

The bottom and second layer can both be pre-rendered images made to suit arbitrary dimensions using `[UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth::]`.

To apply the topmost layer's alpha channel to the second layer, draw the topmost layer on to the second layer's image using `UIContextDrawImage` with blend mode of `kCGBlendModeSourceIn`. Then composite the result on top of the bottom most layer image and you should have something like what `UIToolBar` renders.

Comment: Thanks, this is sort of the information I was looking for.  Of course, I was hoping someone had some code to point me to, but hopefully the clues you gave is enough for me to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [UIButton reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) you will probably want to create an instance and then use;

`- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state`

Where you have `UIControlState` with these possible values;

- `UIControlStateNormal`
- `UIControlStateHighlighted`
- `UIControlStateDisabled`
- `UIControlStateSelected`
- `UIControlStateApplication`
- `UIControlStateReserved`

There is also the property `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` which by default is `NO` but will provide a glow around a button when tapped.